# What is the difference between concentration and effective concentration?

Tags: concentration, solvents

What exactly is effective concentration in simple terms? From what I can understand it is the 'real' concentration taking part in the reaction instead of the concentration of the solute. Also, if I am right, should the effective concentration always be less than the concentration?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. While it may seem strange at first we do not use salutations in our Questions and Answers. Please use the upvote button to say thanks, or leave a comment how the post can be improved.

Comment: I,ve read effective concentration is often higher than the actual concentration, i don´t understand why. It says it represents a ratio of equilibrium for inter and intra molecular reactions in this paper: Urea Dependence of Thiol-Disulfide Equilibria in Thioredoxin: Confirmation of the Linkage Relationship and a Sensitive Assay for Structure? Tiao-Yin Lin and Peter S. Kim* Whitehead Institute for Biomedical Research, Nine Cambridge Center, Cambridge, Massachusetts 021 42, and Department of Biology, Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Cambridge, Massachusetts 021 39 Received January 10, 1989